# Best way to have a exe file with python

Tags: python, anaconda, pyinstaller, cx-freeze, auto-py-to-exe

I am attempting to create a exe file for an application that uses three .py files with functions and some libraries (pandas, tkinter, win32com...).

I want to create this for some people of my company. I'm using Anaconda as environment and tried auto-py-to-exe and cx_freeze to exe compilation. Some of the issues that I'm having are this:

1. I always need to disable windows defender or create an exeption to
   the folder to run the final exe file
2. When I share it with my collegues in a Sharepoint folder it doesn't
   work for them, it looks like some of the libraries are using paths
   with my local folder.
3. The final folder with the exe file is very heavy (around 200MB)
   including a lot of libraries that i don't need, some of the numpy
   related libraries are the heaviest.

I will appreciate any help with this, I've work hard to develop the application but I can't share it to others and that is the objetive.

Thanks!

Comment: `pandas` is large and requires `numpy`, which is large, so you cannot do much about the file size.

Comment: don't use `-onefile` it causes a lot of false positives, otherwise you should probably have someone with experience take a look at your project.

Comment: Post your code. or create a [mre] if you actually want help

Comment: It is strange, A person whi was in my company some years ago developed Python apps with one file exe, and it has the same libraries than mine and the size is around 40MB. I dont know if is my code because I tried with more simple code only with pandas creating a dataframe and still the same.

Comment: @Ignpl you should probably ask him

Comment: If I could i would do it